# Why does not the background color get applied from props using state for a styled component div using react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i want the background color of the styled component div to change to grey when state active is true using react and typescript.

below is my code,

```
function Parent() {
    const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <StyledDiv active={active}>
                Element whose background should change
            </StyledDiv>
        </Wrapper>
    );
}

const StyledDiv = styled.div<{ active?: boolean }>`
    ${({ active }) =>
        active &&
        `background-color: ${(props: any) => props.grey}`};
`;
```

From the above code background color doesnt change to grey if accessed from props.

What works?

```
const StyledDiv = styled.div<{ active?: boolean }>`
    ${({ active }) =>
        active &&
        'background-color:grey'};
`;

           OR
 const StyledDiv = styled.div<{ active?: boolean }>`
     background-color: ${(props: any) => props.grey};
`;
```

I am not sure whats wrong with this. could someone help me fix this. i want to use props to change background color based on active state.

thanks.

Comment: what colour is it supposed to be when it is active or inactive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the `active` prop that is defined as part of the props of the `StyledDiv` styled component, to dynamically set the `div`'s `background-color`,

```
 const StyledDiv = styled.div<{ active?: boolean }>`
     background-color: ${({ active }) => active ? 'blue' : 'grey'};
`;
```

Comment: thanks how do i keep it to grey if active and background-color to what is has already ?. i was trying to use initial if not active. but not working

Comment: Hmm.. Do you know what is the initial colour you have set?

Comment: hm okay fixed it like this background-color: ${props =>
    props.active
      ? props.grey
      : props.white};